# which client side js library can I use for file upload where file size can be restricted

Tags: javascript, client-side-validation

Which js library can I use to upload files from any browser and will allow client-side restriction of the file size

Comment: Try [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). I used this and it works with any server side platform.

Comment: The best library of all of the ones mentioned due to its support, feature set, documentation, and pace of feature development is Fine Uploader.   Http://fineuploader.com.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [jquery File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)

it has option

> maxFileSize
>
> The maximum allowed file size in bytes.
>
> Type: integer Default: undefined Example: 10000000 // 10 MB Note: This
>   option has only an effect for browsers supporting the File API.

But old browsers don't support this feature. And unlikely there are any way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

dropzone.js can. [dropzone website](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
their example:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
      done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI
We using this library in our web projects, works fine in any browsers except android default browser.